# Windows 7 clean install becomes corrupt after reboot (repeated many fresh installs)

Tags: windows-7, boot, ssd, filesystem-corruption

My laptop keeps crashing on boot after clean Windows 7 install.

Computer: Samsung NP900X3C-A04HK (256GB SSD, 8GB RAM)
  OS to install: Windows 7 Ultimate SP1 (not from Samsung, own fresh Windows)

I purchased this laptop about a year ago, never booted it into the Windows Home that was installed on it, installed directly Ubuntu on the machine. Full disc encryption was the selected install, so of course it wiped the complete disc (including the Samsung Recovery Partition).

After some time, I felt like going back to Windows, as Windows 7 is actually quite nice, so I went to buy a fresh Windows 7 Ultimate with Service Pack 1.

Now to the tricky part. Windows installs perfectly, and after installing all Windows updates, drivers from Samsung, software I need, it is time for shutting it down and go to bed. Starting it up again, and it is not booting, these are the type of errors I have gotten so far (fresh installed it more then a dozen times now, and tried different suggestions from threads on the net). Windows failed to start...

Status: 0xc000000f
Info: The boot selection failed because a required device is inaccessible.

---

File: /boot/bcd
Status: 0xc000000f
Info: an error occurred while attempting to read the boot configuration data.

```
Windows Boot Manager  

Windows failed to start. A recent hardware or software change might be the cause.  
To fix the problem:

  1. Insert your Windows installation disc and restart your computer. 
  2. Choose your language settings, and then click "Next."
  3. Click "repair your computer."

If you don't have this disc, contact your system administrator or computer
manufacturer for assistance. 

  File: \boot\bcd

  Status: 0xc000000f

  Info: An error occurred while trying to read the boot configuration data.
```

---

And some other errors, not all the same. I don't remember all of this.

I have run different disc checks, and all says my SSD is in perfect shape.

**Note:** Soft reboots from Windows menu works, never gets corrupted, but if I **Shutdown** and then start it up again, this is when it happens.

Can someone help me not get back to Ubuntu? What can be the cause, and how can it be fixed so I do not get there problems again?

Comment: Do you have another boot CD?

Comment: Only the Win 7 install (on a usb stick)... Do you mean as a recovery cd? I want to solve so that the "corruption" doesn't happen again, I don't want to fix the boot for each time I shut down the machine :)

Comment: When clean installing W7, delete all old partitions first, then click next to install W7, Do Not pre-format the disk.

Comment: Moab, I did that, no pre-format of the disk.

Comment: Typo in model number, it should be NP900X3C-A04HK.

Comment: Typo again, it should be NP900X3A-A04HK

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is: do not be stupid and ignorant...

I downloaded the wrong drivers, I downloaded for NP900X3C-A04HK, but I should have downloaded for NP900X3A-A04HK.

After upgrading of all drivers, all went well... Have rebooted, shutdown, sleep, etc, and no problems anymore.

The problem was probably that the chipset/motherboard drivers were not compatible, or buggy (older version)...

Comment: I agree with your fix. It was possible that it had something to do with the drivers, but more or less there could have been some other issues. I'd like to point out that Windows 7 Ultimate is designed more for computers that have at least 16 GB's of RAM.